# how to start Activty randomly in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

i want to implement simple game. In game there are only three pictures which will displayed to gesture on it. but i need to start game each time with different pictures.

Means if first time i play the game. it will show 2nd image to draw, then 1st to draw to draw, then third to draw. Game End

if i play game 2nd time. order of images should be changed.

Any guide ...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onCreate`, load your three images into an ArrayList and then call `Collections.shuffle(imageList)`. Then use the first image in the array. If you don't want to do all the work of loading the images, use an ArrayList of the image resource IDs.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick reply. I got that. i just want to know that what is the best approch. One is to use three different Activies with there xml.  and 2nd is to use ViewFlipper. Thanks